# In a NodeJS Blockchain, does this code create a basic peer to peer blockchain that checks the previous block's hash?

Tags: node.js, blockchain, cryptocurrency

```
// Import modules
const SHA512 = require("crypto-js/sha512");
var readline = require('readline-sync');

//Transactions are important so miners don't continuously mine blocks 
and spam the blockchain (proof of work)
class Transaction {
    constructor(fromAddress, toAddress, amount){
        this.fromAddress = fromAddress;
        this.toAddress = toAddress;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}

class Block {
    constructor(timestamp, transactions, previousHash = '') {
        this.previousHash = previousHash;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.transactions = transactions;
        this.hash = this.calculateHash();
        this.nonce = 0;
    }

    calculateHash() {
        return SHA512(this.previousHash + this.timestamp + 
        JSON.stringify(this.transactions) + this.nonce).toString();
    }

    mineBlock(difficulty) {
        while (this.hash.substring(0, difficulty) !== Array(difficulty 
        + 1).join("0")) {
            this.nonce++;
            this.hash = this.calculateHash();
        }

        console.log("BLOCK MINED: " + this.hash);
    }
}


class Blockchain {
    constructor() {
        this.chain = [this.createGenesisBlock()];
        this.difficulty = 3;
        this.pendingTransactions = [];
        this.miningReward = 10;
    }

    createGenesisBlock() {
        return new Block(Date.now(), [], "0");
    }

    getLatestBlock() {
        return this.chain[this.chain.length - 1];
    }

    getAllBlocks() {
        return this.chain;
    }

    minePendingTransactions(miningRewardAddress){
        let block = new Block(Date.now(), this.pendingTransactions, 
        this.getLatestBlock().hash);
        block.mineBlock(this.difficulty);

        console.log('Block successfully mined!');
        this.chain.push(block);

        this.pendingTransactions = [
            new Transaction(address1, miningRewardAddress, 
            this.miningReward)
        ];
    }

    createTransaction(transaction){
        this.pendingTransactions.push(transaction);
    }

    getBalanceOfAddress(address){
        let balance = 0;

        for(const block of this.chain){
            for(const trans of block.transactions){
                if(trans.fromAddress === address){
                    balance -= trans.amount;
                }

                if(trans.toAddress === address){
                    balance += trans.amount;
                }
            }
        }

        return balance;
    }

    isChainValid() {
        for (let i = 1; i < this.chain.length; i++){
            const currentBlock = this.chain[i];
            const previousBlock = this.chain[i - 1];

            if (currentBlock.hash !== currentBlock.calculateHash()) {
                return false;
            }

            if (currentBlock.previousHash !== previousBlock.hash) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}

let brewcrypt = new Blockchain();

console.log('\n\n Latest block is:', brewcrypt.getLatestBlock());
console.log('\n-----------------------------');


var address1 = readline.question('\n\nEnter your blockchain address - ');
var address2 = readline.question('\nEnter the address you are sending to - ');

brewcrypt.createTransaction(new Transaction(address1, address2, 10));

if(address2 == address1) {
    console.log('You cannot send transactions to yourself...');
    return process.exit();
}

var blockinput = readline.question('Enter amounts of transaction blocks to be mined -  ');

for(i = 0; i <= blockinput; i++) {
    console.log('\n Starting the miner...');
    brewcrypt.minePendingTransactions(address2);

    console.log('\nBalance of second address is', brewcrypt.getBalanceOfAddress(address2));
    console.log('\n Is chain valid?: ', brewcrypt.isChainValid());
}

console.log('\n\n Blockchain is:', brewcrypt.getAllBlocks());
console.log('\n-----------------------------');
```

So I am learning about blockchains, and I was wondering would this (very basic) blockchain be considered peer to peer? Just kind of looking at how the blocks check the previous blocks using hashes, and if that would be considered peer to peer in a really basic form? If not, can you explain to me what would be a peer to peer blockchain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *not* peer to peer but *is* a blockchain. Blockchains are generally used in a *network* of nodes, so to make this simple blockchain peer to peer you just have to create a system where whenever a new block is created it is relayed to all the nodes in that network. Also, whenever a transaction is created it should be relayed to all the nodes in the network so that it can be included in the next block.

Comment: Ok, awesome! I figured I might be able to use PeerJS to use a peer to peer network.